# use a button type submit but not for submitting form

Tags: jquery, html

I really need a button type submit for make an autocomplete works.But I do not  want to submit the form with it.Is there any way to have a button type submit not for submitting form??

this is my html:

```
<form  class="ajax" action="ajax.php?{$my_admin_module}_do&action=new">
            <tr >
                <td > کلمات کلیدی: </td>
                <td ><input type="text"  id="keyword" name="keyword" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" />
                    <!--<input type="button" name="button_1" value="افزودن" class="btn btn-primary" id="add" style="margin: 10px"/>-->
                    <button type="submit" name="btn" id="add">add</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr >
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
            </tr>
 </form>
```

jaquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#add").click(function(){
       var keyword=$("#keyword").val();
       $( ".keywords" ).append( "<input type='hidden' name='keywords[]' value='"+keyword+"'>"+keyword+"،" );
       $("#keyword").val("");
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `preventDefault()` may work

Comment: use <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return false;" />

Comment: it works.tanks:) @Mohammad

Answer (score 0):

> use "return false;" to prevent form submission.

```
<form  class="ajax" action="ajax.php?{$my_admin_module}_do&action=new">
            <tr >
                <td > کلمات کلیدی: </td>
                <td ><input type="text"  id="keyword" name="keyword" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" />
                    <!--<input type="button" name="button_1" value="افزودن" class="btn btn-primary" id="add" style="margin: 10px"/>-->
                    <button type="submit" name="btn" id="add" onclick="return false;">add</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr >
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return false;"/></td>
            </tr>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#add").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
       var keyword=$("#keyword").val();
       $( ".keywords" ).append( "<input type='hidden' name='keywords[]' value='"+keyword+"'>"+keyword+"،" );
       $("#keyword").val("");
   });
});
```